# Do "acres" still matter for how I plant trees/flowers?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In the first Animal Crossing there were sectors of the map like A1 and D4, and to get a perfect town you needed just enough, but not too many, trees/etc in all areas.

Does New Leaf work like that in that there can be too many trees in one area or can I put trees/flowers pretty much anywhere, even in tight bundles? My current plans include a dense orchard for fruits and a lot of flowers in one area so they can breed freely and so it's easier to keep them watered.

Comment: I think you have put all the information I could find out about these into the question already. My take is that its a tree that just has a chance to die, so keep a fruit in reserve. I am hoping it is a way to make your Local fruit as worth while as non-local fruit (which ends up becoming local fruit :D)

Comment: I've never actually gone for a Perfect Town in any of the games. So. Much. Work.

Comment: @FAE I never went for perfect per se, but the closer you got to perfect, the more people would move in, so I always tried to make it as good as possible.

Answer (score 4):

Each town should have about **16x16** inner linear squares for each Acre (attributed by previous games) and still by game factors in New Leaf. Usually a perfect town should consist of about 13-14 range of trees and about 3-5 flowers near a Villagers home (changes moods about gardening and perfecting a town on their behalf) and scattered 3-4 flowers for the acre.

Selecting the ordnance to **BEAUTIFY 'NEW LEAF TOWN' PROJECT** allows the Villagers to forcefully inherit the ability to water flowers and keep the balance of the Town. Not sure how this ordnance affects the Police Station items.

This game by far has the most acres that affect the game's Perfection. If ever completed, the Player will receive a Golden Watering Can that makes wilted flowers into **GOLD FLOWERS** used for presentation, faster hybrid breeding and nonwilting purposes. This ordnance also allows the flowers to not wilt when pondering into a time warp/timeturner/time travel effect. {Sometimes a player may use a differecnt 3DS and forget the time is mismatched and finds wilts in a town.}

It is more on over about the **TYPE** of town constructed/chosen and is based on the area that is balanced around you. Certain town maps have less beach front than others. This is recognized and the remarks from Isabelle on Villager views are fitted to the location of the town. More over, certain areas are patch work or bare stumped areas that have no trees or constructions; these are what Villagers worry on most.

Each sector has the ability to house more trees than any other game *(for the exception of Animal Crossing 64/Gamecube's ability to cross plant trees side-by-side diagonally)*.

Villagers are more worried/concentrated/focused on their given constructions that are asked consequentially in a face-to-face conversation.

So far I have planted many trees all throughout town and the complaint remains "Not enough in one **AREA**", but I have not found any criteria listing them as acres.

The focus of the player's game is based on planting bamboos, making a planting center, and beatifying with many post around without the use of trees blocking their visibility as well.

"Perfect"/"Delicious" Gold Fruit are available by either making the uprighting of a town or by planting those had. It increases game points but as these trees are fragile be sure to plant each one found to keep ranking positive position points from Villagers.

Also, the use of grass is still wears but does not really affect perfection and is luckily slower than the previous ACCF game.

Suggestions: I do the same as well, as flowers scattered are hard to keep track of and the amount of trees in an area are easier to find exotic fruit apart from natives. Just construct from the Mayor's seat and do things that help the town.

***Best Wishes***